# Getting CSS of an unappended element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am generating specific DOM elements dynamically for a specific layout. In certain cases I am able to get the width of a previously created element using jQuery (to determine other layout factors).

`var width = parseInt((jQuery(element).css("width")));`

However this only works **after the element has been appended to the window.** Is there any way to get the theoretical width of an element which is generated, but not yet appended to the window?

(Extra info: Down at the function's bare bones, I am simply generating these with a `document.createElement()`)

Comment: Look at the width of the future parent?

Comment: Don't think it is possible. For example, the parent element may have class `container` and css rules has `.container > div { width: 10px; }`  You can not know, that the element will be 10 pixels width until you add it. The better way is to add element, get css value and remove element back.

Comment: The widths are always variable based on the div's content. I don't want to remove the element though, and I was hoping to just use temporary `var`'s. I think I'll just have to assign them as `this.` objects and call their width back with an internal function after everything is appended. Thanks guys.

Comment: It's not possible to get the width of an element before it is added to the DOM because the width is not determined until it has been added to the layout. A possible workaround I suppose could be to append to a hidden iframe, then call $('#iframe element').width() or absolutely position them off the screen

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very practical or useful but I just wrote this function which creates a 'sandbox' by cloning the parent and placing it in the dom offscreen.

```
var getStyle = function($parent, $element, props){
    if(typeof props == 'string'){props = [props];}
    var $sandbox = $parent.clone().css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'inline-block',
        width: $parent.width(),
        height: $parent.height(),
        top: -1000,
        left: -1000
    });
    $('body').append($sandbox);
    $sandbox.append($element);
    var result = {};
    for(var i=0;i<props.length;i++){
        var p = props[i];
        if(p == 'width'){ result[p] = $element.width(); }
        else if (p == 'height'){ result[p] = $element.height(); }
        else{ result[p] = $element.css(p); }
    }
    $sandbox.remove();
    return result;
}


console.log(
    getStyle(
        $('#name'),                    //parent
        $('<div>helo</div>'),          //new elemen 
        ['width','height','color']     //properties to fetch
    )
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/beXyM/1/